# Empty target/classes after maven compiles

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have java project with maven and compiling worked well in Eclipse Mars. After upgrading to Neon when I use in eclipse run>maven "clean compile" in console there is shown "Compiling 108 source files to D:\eclipse\testproject\target\classes" correctly and "BUILD SUCCESS" at the end of building. But in "classes" folder there are not .class files.

When I use context menu for project "Maven>Update project" .class files appears in target\classes. I tried to remove explicit compiler plugin in pom, to use external maven.

Is there any tip how to resolve the problem?

edit: With pure maven compiling works. And I noticed in eclipse it writes "compiling" but it's much faster then on console with maven like only writing

Comment: Select make sure that if you are using project explorer or package explorer, after the maven install, the project itself is refreshed using `F5` key or right click and Refresh

Comment: Yes, I know about Package explorer. I use Navigator. As I wrote after maven>update there are classes.

Comment: What builders do you have in your project? Look in project's contextual menu > builders.

Comment: Faceted Project Validation Builder, Java Builder, Spring Project Builder, Maven Project Builder, Validation